# How to pass array to use SDImage to display image in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Here I am displaying images in `imageView`. I am able to display image but only single image in all rows of `TableView` I am using **SDWebImage** with swift for the first time. So I want to pass the array in the following code to display the respective images in each row.Here I am successfully displaying name by passing it through array now just wanted to display the images.

**NOTE** : see the code in comments below but its giving error want to pass the same array but don't know how to write in swift.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : TableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell        
    let strTitle : NSString = arrDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("clip_name") as! NSString        
    cell.clipName.text = strTitle as String 
    cell.videoImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:"http://example.com/test/images/clips", arrDict(indexPath.r‌​ow).objectForKey("clip_image_path")))    
    return cell

}
```

Comment: Sorry, what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: No error but i want to pass the array to it as i have many images like i have used for displaying name same way i have to display all the images see the commented code

Comment: Not sure what's exactly the problem, but have you tried to do it the same way how you set the title?
`let imageUrl = NSString = arrDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("clip_image_path") as! NSString
cell.videoImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:imageUrl))`

Comment: see the code now i have to pass it like that way using url and value for key but don't know how to write it correctly @fiks

Comment: Could you please post what kind of problem you are getting and why you can't use `valueForKey`?

Comment: it is saying cannot call value for non function type 'NSMutableArray'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append your image name with your `URL` like this way.

```
let imagePath = String(format: "http://example.com/test/images/clips/%@",arrDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("clip_image_path") as! NSString)
cell.videoImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imagePath))
```

Comment: see the code now i have to pass it like that way using url and value for key but don't know how to write it correctly

Comment: i think `clip_image_path` key contain the url of image

Comment: Thanks for the help @Nirav